# How to setup appium flutter driver for automation project?

Tags: java, flutter, appium

I'am new to Appium-flutter-driver,i am referred this website [https://github.com/truongsinh/appium-flutter-driver][1]., the JAVA example is not clear.

Unable to configure the driver in my project.I am using JAVA with IntelliJ as IDE I have installed the Appium-flutter-driver in my system using the given command "npm i -g Appium-flutter-driver" in GitHub. But unable to configure driver into my project. There is no ".jar" file.It would be helpful if get any sample code base

Need Help:
1.How to configure the Appium-flutter-driver into project?
2.How to does "enableFlutteDriverrExtension()" work and where should i put this?
3.How to create a apk in debug mode?

Thanks in advance.